# How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator also access Sqlite?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, connection-string

I have create Set up file for WPF application and the database is SQLite DB. After the installation the SQLite DB is located this path in C folder, and the application is running properly on any computer that without an administrator Password PC.

C:\Program Files (x86)\myCompany\myScanApp.

```
public SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\myCompany\myScanApp\test.s3db;");
```

The problem is, it is failing to login after running this application if any other administrator password set PC. How can I solve this problem?

How can I access Sqlite DB from C drive after installation WPF application if pc have administrator password ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1074835/make-visual-studio-solution-filessln-always-executed-as-administrator Check this question I had similar problem. See if helps

Comment: @mybirthname I have done that, still it is not happening. How can I access Sqlite DB from C drive after installation WPF application if pc have administrator password ?